# R: keyword extraction with naive bayes

Tags: r, keyword, extract

I've got some documents and for each document I've got their keywords. Now I want to use these documents to TRAIN a model. My data looks as follows:

```
postag <- list()   
tfidf <- list()   
labels <- list()
```

One element of each list represents a document. There are 50 documents. So
`postag[[1]]` is a vector with the part of speech tagging for each word in document 1, `tfidf[[1]]` is a vector with the tfidffactor for each word in document 1, `labels[[1]]` is a vector with the labels (0 = no keyword, 1 = keyword). NOTE: the words for each document are ordered: So `postag[[1]][1]` is the POS for the first word in document 1, `tfidf[[1]][1]` is the tfidffactor for the same word in document 1, and `labels[[1]][1]` says if this word is a keyword.

Now I want like to use these 50 documents to train a (naive bayes) model that predicts if a word is a keyword or not. The features are tfidf factor and the POS. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [e1071 package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html):

```
data(iris)
m <- naiveBayes(Species ~., data = iris)
predict(m, iris)
```

Note that the column `Species` must be factor variable
For example:

```
iris["Species"]<- as.factor(iris["Species"])
```

but in this case `Species` was a factor already, so you don't have to change it.